# Dropdate Array Error

Tags: fieldtype, date, dropdate

Using Dropdate 2.2.0 and EE 2.5.1

Outputting the field gives me this:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 4096

Message: Argument 2 passed to Dropdate_ft::replace_tag() must be of the type array, boolean given, called in     /Users/Chad/Repositories/hhc/site/system/expressionengine/libraries/channel_entries_parser/components/Custom_field    .php on line 125 and defined

Filename: dropdate/ft.dropdate.php

Line Number: 338

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

Filename: dropdate/ft.dropdate.php

Line Number: 357

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at     /Users/Chad/Repositories/hhc/site/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 412
```

Can someone direct me to a fix for this? I couldn't see anything obvious in the code. Line 338 is

```
public function replace_tag($field_data = '', Array $params = array(), $tagdata = '')
```

and the param in question is Array $params = array()

Answer (score 1):

That add-on is now discontinued, I'm using v3 successfully though - you can find it in the [GitHub account](https://github.com/experience/dropdate.ee_addon/tree/develop) under the Develop branch.

There's a mention of array_merge in the errors (on my version of DropDate it's line 482 in _build_settings method), this tries to intersect array keys regarding settings. Try going to the settings for the fieldtype in EE backend to see if that updates anything, I get this message when I go there:

> We lured you here under false pretences.
>
> There are no global settings, but ExpressionEngine won’t update a
>   fieldtype unless you visit its global settings page. Obviously.
>
> Just click the “Submit” button, and get back to your nice life where
>   you don’t have to deal with this nonsense for a living.

...So clearly it's done something...!

Otherwise, (on my version) display_var_tag calls replace_tag, so you could add a check on that:

```
public function display_var_tag($var_data, Array $params, $tagdata)
{
    if (!is_array($params)) {
        return $this->replace_tag($var_data);
    } else 
        return $this->replace_tag($var_data, $params);
    }
}
```